# Filtering / Excluding columns in MapReduce

Tags: design-patterns, hadoop, mapreduce, filtering

I'm wondering what's the best practice to implement M/R filter which will do the following:

Let's say there is a key value pair:

Key: IntegerID, Value: n integer values. For Example:

1 | 1 2 2 3 3 **0** 6

2 | **0** 3 4 5 6 7 8

3 | 1 5 2 6 2 2 6

I would like to filter (exclude) columns that contain '**0**'

Desired output:

1 | 2 2 3 3 6

2 | 3 4 5 6 8

3 | 5 2 6 2 6

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't look like the best fit for M/R at all, since a reducer will need to see all values from all rows to make a "decision" regarding a column.

I'd be interested to see what the actual problem is and why you decided to go with M/R in the first place.

If I *had* to do this in M/R

I'd have the mapper separate each row into a ([col#,rowkey],value) pairs - the col# is so all data from one column will end up in one reducer (who can decide whether to ditch the column or not). The row_id will be used to combine the results from all the reducers back to a single row.

For example the first row from your example will be sent from mapper to reducer as:

([0,1],1)

([1,1],2)

([2,1],2)

([3,1],3)

([4,1],3)

([5,1],0)

([6,1],6)

Then you'll need a partitioner that will partition the map output to reducers based on the column number (i.e. the first element of the [col#,rowkey]) pair. Also write a custom comparator, so the map results will arrive to the reducer sorted by the value.

This way the reducer will just need to look at the first value - if its 0, we know the column contains a 0 and the reducer can exit without doing anything else.
If its not 0, it should act as an identity reducer - just output all the results from the mapper as is.

Now you need a second M/R job to put it back together in the original format:
The mapper will not do anything.
A custom partitioner will send all the results with the same rowkey to the same reducer. You can use a total-order partitioner if preserving row order in the final result set is important.
A custom comparator will order the data in each partition by rowkey and the col#.

The reducer will write all values for the same row one by one in one string and then output it as a line.

Comment: Let me try to explain a bit more. This is basically a simple bioinformatics problem. I'll try to simplify it as possible:

Let's say we have a group of 100 people with the part of their genome, so a single row would be in a format:

PersonID | Genotype [1..N] where Genotype is an array with the values from the set (0,1,2,-9) -> -9 is missing data.

An example of a file  
([1] 1 0 1 -9)  
([2] 0 0 0 2)  
([3] -9 1 2 0)  
I would like to exclude rows (an easy and M/R fit) and columns that have percentage of missing data (-9) bigger than P

Does this makes sense?

Comment: Later on, during the processing, I have one more format which can be a better fit. In this format, data is pivoted in some sense:

GenotypeID (it's usually called SNP) | Genotype value, PersonID[0..M]

So if we have this as an input:

([1] 1 0 1) 
([2] 0 0 0) 
([3] 1 1 2) 

An equivavalent form would be

([1]-SNPid 0 - SNP value 2 - PersonId) ([1] 1 1 3) ([2] 0 1 2) ([2] 1 3) ([3] 0 2) ([3] 1 1) ([3] 2 3). 

It looks to me that this format is more appropriate for this sort of filtering, if you have any comment it would be very useful. 

Also if you have any questions please let me know!

Comment: Since you need to exclude based on "percentage of missing data" - I'd take a sample of the data and use a small python script to determine which columns have high percent of missing data. Then use a map-only job to efficiently eliminate those rows.

Comment: That is always an opotion, still I'd like to have everything on Hadoop, since it is going to be run on a huge data set. Anyway, thank you very much.